# File.delete() returns false

Tags: java, logging, file-io, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I have created a file from my java programming, and am logging some data use Apache Commons Logging API, specifically the Log4j implementation.

After the logging has been done, I am setting the reference to the Log class as null. When I now try to delete the file to which I have been logging, File.delete() returns false.

Deleting the file from windows explorer during debugging (at the point just before File.delete() is called), I get the notification "cannot delete: being used by another program".

There are no open dependencies on the file from my code (all streams are closed). The only object that could be accessing the file is the Log object, which I have set to null before calling File.delete()

Is there anyway I can see what specific object is holding a reference to the file resource?
Is there any other way to force the Log object to release resource, other than setting it to null?
Can I force a delete on the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just setting the variable to null doesn't force the object to be garbage collected. Also, there's a chance that it's registered in some sort of static map - you'd have to check the implementation to be sure. (I think some versions use weak references, but others don't.)

Is there any reason you *have* to delete the file right then? You might want to try `File.deleteOnExit()`, which *may* have a better chance of deleting the file - although it depends on exactly what the timing is like. (Also, beware of a [possible memory leak](http://puneeth.wordpress.com/2006/01/23/filedeleteonexit-is-evil/) if you call `deleteOnExit` repeatedly.)

Could you just delete the file after the application has finished, or possibly on the next start-up?

Alternatively, can you use a log implementation which rolls the files over - try to force a rollover, and then delete the old file?

Comment: I am writing a test that will be automatically executed on a code repository. I cannot change the implementation of the code I am testing, so cannot move from Log4j. How can I force garbage collection on the objects that I have set to null?

Comment: @Shailesh: It's important that you understand that you can't set an *object* to null, only a *variable*. If that variable was the only thing referring to the object, then it will be eligible for garbage collection - but I suspect you'll find there are other references buried within log4j. If this is a test, you may want to try to configure log4j not to use files for logging at all - logging into a StringBuilder or something similar would be better.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about Log4j setting multiple references to the object. Logging to a StringBuilder will be the best workaround for me.

Answer (score 3):

In your case the logger is writing it in the file
-  The file is locked by another process.

---

**Updates:**

The problem is that the log4js' appender has a write lock on your file. So while the appender is not closed, you cannot delete the file. A solution would be you generated smaller files, or to set the append flag to false, so when you restart your server, the old log file is deleted automatically.

Try using

```
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown();
```

Shutting down make sure that all the processes that are using log files are terminated and this way resolved the issue.

Make sure to call the `close()` method of our own Appender implementation (which is a subclass of AppenderSkeleton), so that it properly closes the appenders from getAllAppenders().